# Magento 2 : Undefined index error after cloning database

Tags: magento2

I created a staging instance of magento 2 from production instance.

- Exported DB and imported to newly created staging DB
- Copied files from production directory to staging directory
- Changed the URL in **config_data** table

After doing this I have been getting **undefined index error**, it goes off if define a primary key in that table, but now the error shows with different table with primary key, How to resolve this. Is there a way or a query to set primary key and index for all tables in magento2 ?

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: PK_CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY in /home/synergo/public_html/staging/magento2/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/AbstractEntity.php on line 769
```